# How do I add popper.js to a Laravel 8 with Bootstrap 5 project?

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-mix, popper.js

I am making a blogging application with Laravel 8 and Bootstrap 5. I use a form placed within a Bootstrap modal to add a post. In addition, I  include a single JavaScript file in the project.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

In `resources/js`, I have an app.js and a bootstrap.js file. In app.js, I require bootstrap.js with

```
require('./bootstrap')
```

From `webpack.mix.js` I compile all that into the single JavaScript file `public\js\app.js`:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

I want to add popper.js to the project, like this:

```
require('./popper');
require('./bootstrap');
```

But, for this purpose, I need the popper.js in `resources/js` along with the other two files. So, I did `npm i @popperjs/core` and `npm run dev`. But it does not compile, and I don't get popper.js in the above-metioned js directory. So, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 - Install `@popperjs/core` using this command: `npm i @popperjs/core`

2 - Add this line to your `bootstrap.js` file:

`window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core');`

3 - Run this command: `npm run dev`

4 - Now you have access to `window.Popper` in your blade files.

Answer (score 1):

In your resources/js/bootstrap.js file, you can use Popper.js and Bootstrap with jQuery like the following.

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core');
    window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
} catch (exception) {
    console.error(exception);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to use "window.<packageName> = require('package'); or just the require('package') in the try catch block?